# Copy edit field value to another edit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Newbie question: MVC4

I have a simple editor (simple text):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyField)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyCopyField)
```

When the user leaves the MyField editor I want the editor of the MyCopyField to have the same text.

How do I paint an ID onto each editor so that I can do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyField` is a string, `EditorFor` will create a textbox using the name of the field as the `ID` and `name`:

```
<input type="text" id="MyField" name="MyField" />
```

Then you can just use jquery to copy the text.

simple jquery:

```
$('#MyField').focusout(function ()
{
      $('#MyCopyField').val($(this).val());                      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AfgAG/13/